# How to get the user with customized verification email in Laravel

Tags: laravel, email

I’m customizing the verification email in Laravel following the instructions in the document.
I have something like this:
AuthServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    VerifyEmail::toMailUsing(function (object $notifiable, string $url) {
        return (new VerificationMail)
            ->to(‘test@example.com’);
}
```

The `VerificationMail`  is a `Mailable` class created with `make` command. I wonder how should I have the `->to` part set to the actual user’s email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, $notifiable is an instance of User. So you just do the below:

```
public function boot()
{
    VerifyEmail::toMailUsing(function (object $notifiable, string $url) {
        return (new VerificationMail)
            ->to($notifiable->email);
}
```